# Jetty - Authentification HTTP - Double request

Tags: java, web-services, http, jetty, http-status-code-401

For REST web services, we set up the Jetty HTTP authentication.

The problem is that each request sent with authentication is performed 2 times, then it is started once

In each case, the first response is an HTTP 401 return, then the query is run again ...

If I disable authentication, I do not have this problem.

Is it possible to avoid this double call? more importantly, how?

here are my logs :

> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.618:DBUG:oejs.Server:REQUEST /project/config/loadTable on AsyncHttpConnection@764904bd,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=3,c=0},r=2
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.620:DBUG:oejs.Server:RESPONSE /project/config/loadTable  401
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.760:DBUG:oeji.nio:destroyEndPoint SCEP@23b9b99d{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12888),d=false,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.971:DBUG:oeji.nio:created SCEP@2aa9bd1d{l(/193.248.145.16:52210)<->r(/195.160.188.114:12888),d=false,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{AsyncHttpConnection@6dbed0cc,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.988:DBUG:oejs.Server:REQUEST /project/config/loadTable on AsyncHttpConnection@6dbed0cc,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=43,c=0},r=1
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.991:DBUG:jndi:InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.991:DBUG:jndi:Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@3abdae7
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.992:DBUG:jndi:Looking up name="jdbc/project"
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:43.992:DBUG:jndi:Looking up name="project"
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.007:DBUG:jndi:InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.007:DBUG:jndi:Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@53408c0d
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.008:DBUG:jndi:Looking up name="jdbc/project"
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.008:DBUG:jndi:Looking up name="project"
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.029:DBUG:jndi:InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.029:DBUG:jndi:Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@591a00b1
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.029:DBUG:jndi:Looking up name="jdbc/project"
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.030:DBUG:jndi:Looking up name="project"
>
> 2013-06-27 12:10:44.314:DBUG:oejs.Server:RESPONSE /project/config/loadTable  200

thank you

Answer (score 0):

401 means that the server requires authentication credentials that the client either has not sent or the ones sent by the client have not been authorized. Some client implementations will resend the request if they receive a 401 including the credentials. If your client is doing that, that would explain why you get the request twice on the server.

The HttpParser toString() method returns the current status of the HttpParser. Here's the code:

```
return String.format("%s{s=%d,l=%d,c=%d}",
        getClass().getSimpleName(),
        _state,
        _length,
        _contentLength);
```

So s is the state. -5 is STATE_HEADER. And l and c represent the length and the contentLength.